# wmz file to gif or jpg

Tags: c#, gif, jpeg

How can i convert the "wmz" file to "gif" or "jpg" file in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WMZ` is a [compressed Windows Metafile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile) which you could first decompress and then [convert to the desired format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twss4wb0(VS.90).aspx) (don't forget to dispose all those `Image` instances which is not done in the MSDN example).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I could decompress and convert to jpg file.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. I could decompress the "wmz" file and convert it to a wmf file. The code is

```
public String DeCompressWMZFile(String wmzFile)
{
    MemoryStream decompressStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(wmzFile));
    GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(decompressStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
    MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
    int readCount;
    byte[] data = new byte[2048];
    do
    {
        readCount = gzipStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        outStream.Write(data, 0, readCount);
    } while (readCount == 2048);
    String imgFile = Path.GetDirectoryName(wmzFile) + "\\" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(wmzFile) + ".wmf";
    File.WriteAllBytes(imgFile, outStream.GetBuffer());
    // Then add the code to create a new word document and insert 
    return imgFile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert WMZ to GIF/PNG/JPG/etc:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://link1.ru/image.wmz");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (Stream inputStream = response.GetResponseStream()) 
{
    using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        Image i = Image.FromStream(gzipStream);
        i.Save("1.gif", ImageFormat.Gif);
    }
}
```